# lxml - function to return cleaned object, not just a string

Tags: python, xml, django, lxml

Here is some code:

```
from lxml import etree
url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=aapl'
data = etree.parse(url) 
root = data.getroot()
finance = root[0]


def clean(var, num):
    var = str(finance[num].attrib).split("'")[-2]
    print var
```

I would like to return the variable as an object that I can call later.

I know what the problem is - the str() - but don't know how to fix it as working with the variable directly doesn't allow me to to do the necessary manipulations with `.attrib` and `.split`

Comment: "I would like to return the variable as an object that I can call later." Please explain this in more details. Could you give an example of how you would like to use your object? Provide a minimal test-case of how you would like to take advantage of the future solution.

Comment: Use `var = finance[num].attrib['data']` - it better clarifies what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to gather information from XML, do:

```
data = dict()
for elem in finance:
    data[elem.tag] = elem.attrib['data']
```

You will get a dictionary in `data` variable like:

```
{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'company': 'Apple Inc.', 'currency': 'USD', 'volume': '19145182' ... }
```

And you'll be able to access particular pieces of info:

```
print data['company']
```

Comment: thanks! that's a much less brittle way of doing it.